# Matplotlib plots messed up

Tags: python, matplotlib, backend

I have a fairly simple plot that suddenly started going crazy after I changed something with the backends for another project using seaborn where a bug makes it necessary to change backend for correct results.

However, I must have done something that changes the way plots are made completely, because somehow the frame of my plots are now gone and the background of plots as well. Here are two plots (data is different, didn't have all backups of the "good ones"), left is the way it is supposed to look like, right is the current.

The only thing I changed was to run the command `export MPLBACKEND="module://WXAgg"`. I have restarted my computer and even reinstalled matplotlib since then to see if this fixes things. But it is still the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am sure it is only my inexperience that makes this appear so difficult to solve...

**Edit** I have continued to look at this, but still can't find a solution. It doesn't appear to be my modification with the backend, but I have no clue what else to blame. I have restored my scripts to older versions that I knew had no problems, and I ran the script at another computer, without any problems!

Here is the script in its current condensed state:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('pdf')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ColumnDensity_withTimeList(inputdirs, species_list, model_data, abundances, times_list, parameter_label, plot_dir, style, single_plots, column_density_limit):

for s in range(0, len(species_list)):
    for d in range(0, len(inputdirs)):
        patches     = []
        radii       = model_data[d]['radii'][:,0]
        f, ax       = plt.subplots(1,1)

        for t in range(0, len(times_list)):

            ax.loglog(radii, abundances, color='black')
            ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='lightgray', linestyle='--')
            f.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
            ax2 =   ax.twinx()
            ax2.semilogy(radii, model_data[d]['temperatures'], 'r--')
            ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature [K]', color='r')
            for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
                tl.set_color('r')

            ax3 =   ax.twinx()
            ax3.set_frame_on(True)
            ax3.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax3.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.2))
            ax3.semilogy(radii, model_data[d]['densities'], 'b--')
            ax3.set_ylabel('Density [cm-3]', color='b')
            for tl in ax3.get_yticklabels():
                tl.set_color('b')

            plt.savefig(filename + ".pdf")
            plt.close()
```

[image: Correct plot]
[image: Faulty plot]

Comment: Is there no one that has a clue what else to try? I have tried normal plots and they are all fine. I have really tried to strip away all command that alters the plot in any way, so as far as I can see there is only left different settings, such as backend, and such, that might be the fault. 
Any hints as to where I should look next?

Comment: try `export MPLBACKEND="TkAgg"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much problems figuring this out, I found out that it was in fact import `seaborn` that was causing my problems. If I moved this to the place where it was used, it could leave other places unaffected, and my problem was solved.

Why importing `seaborn` should change all plots I can't understand, but I know now to be much more careful with where I put my imports...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the only difference between the plots is that on the left boxes are shown and hidden on the right. I'm not sure what seaborn does but it seems that something you did changed the default settings for those parameters.
You can turn the boxes on and off explicitly with `plt.box('off')/plt.box('on')`. For the legend you can pass the argument `frameon = True/False`.

**Edit**:
Try the following: find your rcparams file (`matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`). Paste the following lines into it:

```
axes.facecolor:white      
axes.edgecolor:black
legend.frameon: True
```

Rerun your script.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear. I did changes for the backend for a different plot where I use seaborn. For this example however, I am using purely matplotlib.pyplot. I have added a new figure that shows the problems maybe better. The problem is that the background is gray, and there are odd white lines showing up for some reason when I add my extra axes to the right. 
Please ignore that data itself, I don't have the same dataset to reproduce the "original" working plot anymore. The gray background, the missing frame and the odd white strips in the gray background is the problem.

Comment: Ok so something you did must have changed the default settings for figures. See the edited Answer.

Comment: I tried this, and it did return the plots background colour to white again, but the frame of the plot is still gone. 
I also noticed another difference between the plots: The ticks are pointing outwards from the box in the "failed" plot, but inwards in the "good" plot. Might that shine some more light on the problem?